# jQuery: Variable from URL, with ÆØÅ and what not

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-parameters, urlvariables

I use a script to get a variable from the URL and decode it - "userName" to be preciese.

However the script only works with English characters, and not Danish or other Latin characters. How can I get pass this?

If the name is "Jørgen-Vælle Jürgensen" then the script will output "JÃ¸rgen-VÃ¦lle JÃ¼rgensen" ... not quiet what I expected... :-)

**Script:**

```
//Get the variable userName from URL
$.extend({URLEncode:function(c){var o='';var x=0;c=c.toString();var r=/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*)/;
  while(x<c.length){var m=r.exec(c.substr(x));
    if(m!=null && m.length>1 && m[1]!=''){o+=m[1];x+=m[1].length;
    }else{if(c[x]==' ')o+='+';else{var d=c.charCodeAt(x);var h=d.toString(16);
    o+='%'+(h.length<2?'0':'')+h.toUpperCase();}x++;}}return o;},
URLDecode:function(s){var o=s;var binVal,t;var r=/(%[^%]{2})/;
  while((m=r.exec(o))!=null && m.length>1 && m[1]!=''){b=parseInt(m[1].substr(1),16);
  t=String.fromCharCode(b);o=o.replace(m[1],t);}return o;}
});


$.extend({
    getUrlVars: function () {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    },
    getUrlVar: function (name) {
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
    }
});

_allVars = $.getUrlVars();
var userName = _allVars.userName;

$(".userName").text($.URLDecode(userName));
```

What shouuld I do??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of:**

```
$(".userName").text($.URLDecode(userName));
```

**Use this**

```
$(".userName").text(decodeURI(userName)+ "");
```

The answer is to use JavaScript only, which makes it very simple.

Answer (score 3):

See [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**decode**](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/urlencode-encode-url-decode-urldecode-uri-fix) the url. `$.URLDecode(url)` is your friend =) It's a plugin (there might be a built-in way in jQuery or plain javascript, but this was the first hit on Google) so you'll have to download and include that for it to work.

Comment: Now I have a problem with ÆØÅ (Danish characters. Do you know how I can "translate" them as well?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript decodeURIComponent function to decode the url.